# Can i save PFRelation with method pinInBackground?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfrelation

I try save relation this way

```
[pfBill pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error)
 {
     [relation addObject:pfBill];

     [pfObjectWithRelations pinInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error)
      {
      }];
 }];
```

But i can't do it.

```
    PFRelation *relation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"Relation"];
PFQuery *query = [[relation query] fromLocalDataStore];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"%@", objects);
}];
```

it returns nothing,
but if i save relation with saveEventually its return some objects from local datastore

Comment: Can't do it? Why? Do  you get an error message? What is the message?

Answer (score 0):

Save the object and pin it on success. Until an object is saved (or pushed to `saveEventually` IIRC) it doesn't have an `objectId` and isn't considered as a 'valid' object (so you also can't add it to a relationship).